# SSIS web service task producing "object reference" error

Tags: web-services, ssis

Our care management system uses a web service to import data. I've successfully executed one of its methods using soapUI, and now I want to replicate this with an SSIS 2008 web service task, but I'm running into a problem. I've created the "HTTP Connection Manager" successfully, and specified the location of the "WSDLFile", but when I go to the Input tab and select the Service from the dropdown (there is only one), I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, and and the Method dropdown is empty. Any idea what this is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem with the vendor. While soapUI just calls the web service, .NET tries to build all the necessary structures, and the definition for those structures references a web location that doesn't seem to be active any longer. So it appears that the web service was "half" defined and is crashing because none of the supporting structures are defined.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this in SSIS2008 but had all sorts of trouble in SSIS2005 connecting to sharepoint. In the end I generated a web services proxy class (using wsdl.exe) and used a script task to call the web service and store the xml response in a variable. Then used an xml task to process the XML into the database.